# How can I compute the expected value of the mean of a subset of one variable given the mean of a subset of another variable in a correlated dataset?

Tags: correlation, data-mining

I have a dataset with three variables: "Category", "X", and "Y". "Category" can be one of 5 different values: say A, B, C, D, E.

I know that X and Y are correlated (say their correlation coefficient is 0.4).

I can compute `mean(X)`, `mean(Y)` for the entire data set, as well as `mean(X | Category = A)`, `mean(X | Category = B)`, etc.

Say I have a situation as follows:

```
mean(X) = 0.7
mean(Y) = 0.8

mean(X | Category=A) = 0.5
mean(Y | Category=A) = 0.65
```

Now clearly, the average `X` and `Y` are both lower in the "A" category. What I'd like to know is, assuming that Y influences X (via their correlation), **how much better/worse is the X in category A, given that the Y is on average worse as well**?

---

Intuitively, if I see the following:

```
mean(X) = 0.7
mean(Y) = 0.8
mean(X | Category=A) = 0.5
mean(Y | Category=A) = 0.5
```

Then I could say that X is *better* in the subset of category A, because given the lower Y value, I would expect the X to be lower as well, but it is in fact higher. Similarly, given:

```
mean(X) = 0.7
mean(Y) = 0.8
mean(X | Category=A) = 0.65
mean(Y | Category=A) = 0.8
```

I could intuitively say the X is *worse* by comparison, because the expected mean is 0.7 yet the actual mean was 0.65.

How do I quantify this? I suspect the correlation may be enough, but I am unsure how to proceed.

---

In other words, I want to know how to compute something like:

> What would the expected mean(X | category=A) be given that the mean(Y) is v, the mean(Y | Category=A) is w, and assuming that X | category=A has the same distribution/"behavior"/relation to Y as X itself?

---

[My earlier question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255740/how-to-get-the-magnitude-proportion-ratio-of-the-correlation-between-two-variabl) is an attempt to figure out a tool I could use do this, but I'm not sure if it's the right approach.

Comment: Your formulation following "in other words" is the classic formulation of a regression problem.  Regression, then, would seem to be the tool of choice.  But in this formulation all references to a "category" seem to have disappeared, so what is the connection to the rest of your post?

Comment: @whuber: That is a good question. I'm not sure how to precisely formulate this. What I want to know is "What would the expected mean(X | category=A) be given that the mean(Y) is v, the mean(Y | Category=A) is w, and assuming that X | category=A has the same distribution/"behavior"/relation to Y as X itself"

Comment: That sounds like [tag:multiple-regression].  You are asking to estimate properties of the distribution of $Y$ conditional on values of two other variables, "Category" and "X".

Comment: @whuber: Wouldn't multiple regression only work on independent variables? https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/multiple-regression-using-spss-statistics.php , "You have two or more independent variables [...]", "Your data must not show multicollinearity [...]"

Comment: An excellent Internet rule of thumb for stats research is to exclude, automatically, any resource that includes "SPSS" in its name or title :-).  The fact that *any* dataset of explanatory variables can be expressed in terms of a set of linearly independent variables shows just how wrong that statement is. A quick review of its context indicates (a) it is using "multicollinearity" in a loose sense; it does not refer to perfect collinearity; and (b) it is merely citing an "assumption" that needn't exactly hold. (It's incorrect that this is a standard assumption of multiple regression, though).

Comment: @whuber Maybe you should not condemn every SPSS tutorial.  But it is absolutely true that "independent variables" in regression is a misnomer.  Very often these predictor variables have some correlation between them.  The multicollinearity problem occurs when the correlation is high.  Their are various diagnostics for this. The VIF variance inflation factor is one such measure that has been seen in thread today.

Comment: Searching using "variance inflation factor" gave 157 hits.  One title "Variance Inflation Factor " was posted just 17 hours ago.